# Help with Carbon Fibre

Tags: materials, intermolecular-forces, nanotechnology, carbon-family

I'm having trouble finding articles about carbon fibre that don't contradict other articles.  I just have a few questions about the atomic structure and the intermolecular and intramolecular forces.

So, if we compare graphite's molecular structure to carbon fibre, is carbon fibres structure 3-dimensional compared to graphites linear sheets of carbon???

[image]

Also, I would like to know what forces exist inside carbon fibre.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There is more than one type of carbon, unfortunately. Some do transform to graphite under reasonable conditions, some do not. Thus, properties and structure of carbon fiber depend on  its structure and preparation, and even minor changes in the process can lead to drastic changes in the result.

Comment: my primer into carbons was this paper https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9780470403709.ch1 , though it might be hard to obtain legally.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally carbon fiber is mostly graphitic, but it does contain defects where the carbon has a 3-d non-aromatic structure and allows for cross-linking of the sheets.  We can know that fiber is mostly graphitic because it would not be high temperature stable if it were not.

Comment: You also have to consider scale. It is possible that on a small scale the structure is graphitic, but each "flat" graphite sheet bends on a larger scale creating tubes which on a small scale look like graphite but on a large scale look like fibres.